# How to convert mongodb binary data to json?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, binary-data

I get a list data from mongodb, like below format:

```
[{u'school': 'search', u'name': Binary('63701838-6e3c-4ad4-ae16-4926ac0719e0', 0), u'level': 60, u'avtName': Binary('\xe8\x8b\xa6\xe7\x9c\xa0\xe4\xbd\xa0\xe5\xbf\x83', 0), u'avatarid': Binary('WEZoDaRn1Mmb0ajl', 0), u'charid': Binary('10000', 0)}]
```

How can I conveniently convert this data to json format?

Comment: What is wrong with [`bson.dumps`](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/bson/json_util.html)? Or have not not even looked there?

Comment: yes,I have tried bson.dumps, the result is below:{"_id": {"$oid": "5846707efbdc494457173262"}, "avatars": [{"school": 1, "name": {"$binary": "NzRhNTY0ODQtN2NiNS00ZmYzLWI1NmMtYWJhMjVkZGVlYmE3", "$type": "00"}, "level": 60, "avtName": {"$binary": "5aSn5ryg5ri45L6g", "$type": "00"}, "avatarid": {"$binary": "V0Vad2ZtQXVXelRXSDBFRQ==", "$type": "00"}, "charid": {"$binary": "MTAwMDA=", "$type": "00"}}], "name": {"$binary": "NzRhNTY0ODQtN2NiNS00ZmYzLWI1NmMtYWJhMjVkZGVlYmE3", "$type": "00"}}

Comment: It seems the binary data is base64 encoded

Comment: Please don't try to post code or data in comments. Edit your question instead and just use comments to notify people. But of course it's encoded. JSON is a "string" based format, and could not possibly accept any other representation. If you are expecting something else then it would not be in JSON format. What is the actual purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Use PyMongo's json_util.dumps:

```
from bson import json_util
json_string = json_util.dumps(doc)
```